# Bugzilla/Apache/Windows, "You don't have permission to access / on this server."

Tags: windows, apache-http-server, bugzilla

On 64bit Windows Server 2008 r2, I'm trying to install Bugzilla. Have installed MySQL 5.6, Apache 2.4, Perl 5.20, and Bugzilla 4.4.9+, 64 bit versions all around. I've successfully completed the Bugzilla step where you call `checksetup.pl`, which is the end of the install.

If I go to my browser (Firefox), and type in `http://localhost/`, I get a `403 - FORBIDDEN You don't have permission to access / on this server.`.  I made sure my hosts file had an entry for 'localhost'. I will include here the the last line from my BugZilla error log, my httpd.conf, and the generated 'localconfig' file from running checksetup.pl.
It's got to be something small/stupid, but I'm not experienced enough to know what that would be.  Let me know if there's anything else you need.

Thanks.

## ErrorLog:

> [Fri Jun 19 09:52:29.071794 2015] [authz_core:error] [pid 3392:tid 1156]     >>[client ::1:35188] AH01630: client denied by server configuration:     D:/Apache24/htdocs/

## httpd.conf:

```
Define SRVROOT "/Apache24"
ServerRoot "${SRVROOT}"

Listen 80

LoadModule actions_module modules/mod_actions.so
LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so
LoadModule allowmethods_module modules/mod_allowmethods.so
LoadModule asis_module modules/mod_asis.so
LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so
LoadModule authn_core_module modules/mod_authn_core.so
LoadModule authn_file_module modules/mod_authn_file.so
LoadModule authz_core_module modules/mod_authz_core.so
LoadModule authz_groupfile_module modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so
LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so
LoadModule authz_user_module modules/mod_authz_user.so
LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so
LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so
LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so
LoadModule env_module modules/mod_env.so
LoadModule include_module modules/mod_include.so
LoadModule info_module modules/mod_info.so
LoadModule isapi_module modules/mod_isapi.so
LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so
LoadModule negotiation_module modules/mod_negotiation.so
LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so
LoadModule socache_shmcb_module modules/mod_socache_shmcb.so
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
LoadModule status_module modules/mod_status.so

<IfModule unixd_module>
User daemon
Group daemon

</IfModule>

ServerAdmin bgraham@amci-wireless.com

ServerName localhost:80

<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>
DocumentRoot "D:/Bugzilla"
<Directory "D:/Bugzilla">

    ScriptInterpreterSource Registry-Strict
    Options +ExecCGI +FollowSymLinks
    DirectoryIndex index.cgi index.html
    AllowOverride Limit FileInfo Indexes Options

</Directory>

<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html
</IfModule>

<Files ".ht*">
    Require all denied
</Files>

ErrorLog "logs/error.log"

LogLevel warn

<IfModule log_config_module>
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%m %U\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined

    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common

    <IfModule logio_module>
      LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
    </IfModule>

    CustomLog "logs/access.log" common

</IfModule>

<IfModule alias_module>
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "${SRVROOT}/cgi-bin/"

</IfModule>

<IfModule cgid_module>
</IfModule>

<Directory "${SRVROOT}/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule mime_module>
    TypesConfig conf/mime.types

    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz

    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl

</IfModule>

Include conf/extra/httpd-autoindex.conf
Include conf/extra/httpd-info.conf

Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

<IfModule proxy_html_module>
Include conf/extra/proxy-html.conf
</IfModule>

<IfModule ssl_module>
Include conf/extra/httpd-ahssl.conf
SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
</IfModule>
```

## LocalConf

```
$create_htaccess = 1;
$webservergroup = '';
$use_suexec = 0;
$db_driver = 'mysql';
$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_name = 'bugs';
$db_user = 'bugs';
$db_pass = 'xxxx';
$db_port = 0;
$db_sock = '';
$db_check = 1;
$index_html = 0;
$cvsbin = '';
$interdiffbin = '';
$diffpath = '.';
$site_wide_secret = 'xxx';
```

Comment: This link on StackOverflow got the default page to show up:  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10873295/error-message-forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-on-this-server)  The key phrase was "Require all granted". I'll have to admit to some trepidation using this, but the site must go up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, the answer was to place "Require all granted" in the  "Directory/" 
block of the httpd.conf file . ( I have no clue how to quote HTML in "markdown" ... couldn't figure it out. ) Please see comment above for link to a StackOverflow entry where this was hashed out.